# Проблема с границами вёрстки на разных разрешениях

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
  src: url('BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 300;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}

body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #42c1b0;
}

html{
    font-size: 100%;
}


.meta{
    height: auto;
    min-width: 100% auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.main{
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
     padding: 0 180px 0 150px;
}

.header{
    height: 80px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    width: 1700px auto;
    padding: 0 180px 0 150px;
}


.logo h1{
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #3cc3b5;
}

.korzina {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.korzina img, .korzina h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.korzina h2{
    color: #a1a1a1;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Lobster';
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}




/*Search form*/
.search img{
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
}

.search-form {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.search-form-input {

  width: 435px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 38px 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.search-form-btn {
  /* Позиционирование относительно <form> */
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px; /* 2px - размер border'а поля формы */
  top: 2px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;

  /* Просто тюнинг внешнего вида */
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;      
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*and search form*/

/*Menu*/
.nav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 35px;
    position: relative;  
}

.menu{
    width: 1580px;
    background-color: #4ccfc1;
    padding: 0 120px 0 100px;
}

.menu ul{
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: flex-start;
}

.menu ul li{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 30px;
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 100;
}


.menu ul a:last-child li{
    border:none
}


/*end Menu*/
```

```html
<body>
       <div class="meta">
        <div class="main">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
            <h1>Aditii</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="search">
            <form action="#" class="search-form">
                  <input type="search" class="search-form-input" placeholder="" />
                    <button type="submit" class="search-form-btn">
                    <!-- Сюда можно запихнуть любую картинку на свой вкус -->
                       <img src="img/Search%201.png" alt="">
                    </button>
            </form>
            </div>
            <div class="korzina">
          <img src="img/Korzinka.png" alt=""> 
           <h2>$300</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      <!--- Menu --->
       <div class="nav">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <a href=""><li>Home</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Sale</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Handbags</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Wallets</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Accessories</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Mens Store</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Shotes</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Vintage</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Services</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Contact us</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--- end menu ---->
    </body>
```

Проблема в том, что при просмотре сайта на устройствах с других разрешением сайт отображается некорректно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на скриншоте, за границами сайта виден задний фон. 
Подскажите как мне его убрать или что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: У телепатов сегодня выходной... показали бы код, однако, вы наверно задали фиксированную высоту для блока (контейнера).

Comment: @Arsen Да я бы и скинул код но просто не знаю даже какой, точнее какую часть его

Comment: @Arsen Так ну часть кода добавил.

Comment: Если это только кусок кода, возможно будет легче самому проверить к какому контейнеру ты задал фиксированную высоту ? на изображении справа

Comment: в css добавьте media для меньших разрешений - уберите  `.main{padding: 0 120px 0 100px;}` и поставьте `.nav{width:100%}`

Comment: @Alex                                                                                             
              media screen and (max-width: 1435px){ 
    .nav{
        width:100%
    }
} так или нет?

Comment: @Alex все равно не могу понять где я задал фиксированную высоту

Comment: @BraFik `@media screen and (max-width: 1435px){
  .main{padding:0;}
      .menu{width:100%;}
    }`

Comment: @Alex да я пробовал но все равно когда начинаю уменьшать страницу всё слетает((

Comment: @BraFik Вы настройте Ваш сайт под разные разрешения. У Вас там указана фиксировананная ширина и padding. `@media screen and (max-width: 1435px){
  .main{padding:0;}
      .menu{width:100%;padding:0;}
   .header{padding:0;}
   .search-form-input{width:100%;}
    }` **тест [здесь](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//1dr.ru/test.html&w=414&h=736&a=37)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо настроить сайт под разные разрешения и поддерживаемые устройства. Для этого добавьте **[@media](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media)** для разных разрешений и устройств.

Пример:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1435px){
      .main{padding:0;}
      .menu{width:100%;padding:0;}
      .header{padding:0;}
      .search-form-input{width:100%;}
    }
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
  src: url('BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 300;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #42c1b0;
}

html {
  font-size: 100%;
}

.meta {
  height: auto;
  min-width: 100% auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 180px 0 150px;
}

.header {
  height: 80px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 1700px auto;
  padding: 0 180px 0 150px;
}

.logo h1 {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #3cc3b5;
}

.korzina {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.korzina img,
.korzina h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.korzina h2 {
  color: #a1a1a1;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Lobster';
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}


/*Search form*/

.search img {
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

.search-form {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.search-form-input {
  width: 435px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 38px 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.search-form-btn {
  /* Позиционирование относительно <form> */
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  /* 2px - размер border'а поля формы */
  top: 2px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  /* Просто тюнинг внешнего вида */
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*and search form*/


/*Menu*/

.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 35px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  width: 1580px;
  background-color: #4ccfc1;
  padding: 0 120px 0 100px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.menu ul li {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.menu ul a:last-child li {
  border: none
}


/*end Menu*/


/*media*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1435px) {
  .main {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .header {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .search-form-input {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="meta">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
          <h1>Aditii</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="search">
          <form action="#" class="search-form">
            <input type="search" class="search-form-input" placeholder="" />
            <button type="submit" class="search-form-btn">
                    <!-- Сюда можно запихнуть любую картинку на свой вкус -->
                       <img src="img/Search%201.png" alt="">
                    </button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="korzina">
          <img src="img/Korzinka.png" alt="">
          <h2>$300</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--- Menu --->
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <a href="">
            <li>Home</li>
          </a>
          <a href="">
            <li>Sale</li>
          </a>
          <a href="">
            <li>Handbags</li>
          </a>
          <a href="">
            <li>Wallets</li>
          </a>
          <a href="">
            <li>Accessories</li>
          </a>
          <a href="">
            <li>Mens Store</li>
          </a>
          <a href="">
            <li>Shotes</li>
          </a>
          <a href="">
            <li>Vintage</li>
          </a>
          <a href="">
            <li>Services</li>
          </a>
          <a href="">
            <li>Contact us</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--- end menu ---->
</body>
```

Comment: я попробовал сделать, сделать так так вы написали но почему-то это не сработало( Не могу понять почему? и ещё вопрос мне нужно определённым размерам прописать @media?

Comment: @BraFik вам нужно прописать media для нужных разрешений, не обязательно для каждого если стили совпадают для нескольких разрешений. Для указанного Вами кода в вопросе код из ответа 
 работает. Уточните пожалуйста, что именно у Вас не получилось ?

Comment: получается, я хочу что бы у меня при уменьшении экрана не появлялась та большая полоса заднего фона. Как я показал на скрине. Я задал те параметры которые вы мне дали выше, это работало но только до сужения экрана до 1380px. После же там когда начинается 1378px, начинается тоже самое.

Comment: Я конечно извиняюсь, может я уже задолбал, но может ли быть проблема в слайдере я просто ему задал фиксированную высоту 1280px;

Comment: @BraFik решение дано для кода который есть в вопросе. Как Вы можете видеть для данного кода [отображение на 1378px корректно](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//1dr.ru/test.html&w=1378&h=736) и полоса не появляется.

Comment: да я понял спасибо, ладно буду делать адаптивный слайдер как-то, потому что мне кажется это из-за него, ещё раз спасибо что уделили мне время

Comment: @BraFik если не будет получаться, задайте вопрос на сайте, но помните, что чем лучше будет отображен пример кода для воспроизведения Вашей проблемы, тем более качественным будет ответ.